# ¿Por que me devuelve "Call to undefined method Illuminate\Session\Store::getMetadataBag()" al actualizar laravel a la versión 5.8?

Tags: php, laravel

Al actualizar laravel de la versión 5.2 a la versión 5.8 (no me ha permitido hacer la actualización de la 5.2 a la 5.4 o 5.6) me devuelve el error: "Call to undefined method Illuminate\Session\Store::getMetadataBag()" que por lo que he visto, tiene que ver con el control de sesión, y por mas que busco en la documentación de laravel no encuentro como darle solución. ¿Alguien ha tenido un error como este y ha podido solucionarlo?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ¿Por que me devuelve “Call to undefined method Illuminate\Session\Store::getMetadataBag()” al actualizar laravel a la versión 5.8?

El error ocurre porque dicho método ha sido removido a partir de la [v5.4](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.4/src/Illuminate/Session/Store.php)

La solución es que hagas tu mismo hagas una implementanción donde agregues este método a la clase actual.

- Última versión de la clase con el método: [`Illuminate/Session/Store.php  v5.3`](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.3/src/Illuminate/Session/Store.php)
- Versión la actual de la clase sin el método [`Illuminate/Session/Store.php  v5.8`](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.8/src/Illuminate/Session/Store.php)

Comment: Muchas gracias Marcos, he implementado los métodos que me faltaban y ya funciona correctamente